# Retrofit 2.6.0 exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred

Tags: android, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I have a project with Kotlin coroutines and Retrofit.

I had these dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2'
```

Today I have updated **Retrofit** to **2.6.0** in the project. In https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter it is written that it is deprecated now. In https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-260-2019-06-05 it is written that Retrofit currently supports `suspend`.

So, I removed `retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2` and in Retrofit client changed these lines:

```
        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(SERVER_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(MyGsonFactory.create(gson))
            //.addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory()) - removed it.
            .build()
```

When run, the first request catches an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred<com.package.model.response.UserInfoResponse>
    for method Api.getUserInfo
```

As I understood, instead of `CoroutineCallAdapterFactory()` I could use `CallAdapter.Factory()`, but it is abstract.

If in Api class I change a request adding `suspend` in the beginning:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("user/info/")
suspend fun getUserInfo(@Field("token") token: String): Deferred<UserInfoResponse>

override suspend fun getUserInfo(token: String): Deferred<UserInfoResponse> =
    service.getUserInfo(token)
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred<com.package.model.response.UserInfoResponse>. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Reading https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-260-2019-06-05 I saw:

> New: Support suspend modifier on functions for Kotlin! This allows you
>   to express the asynchrony of HTTP requests in an idiomatic fashion for
>   the language.
>
> @GET("users/{id}") suspend fun user(@Path("id") long id): User
>
> Behind the scenes this behaves as if defined as fun user(...):
>   Call and then invoked with Call.enqueue. You can also return
>   Response for access to the response metadata.
>
> Currently this integration only supports non-null response body types.
>   Follow issue 3075 for nullable type support.

I changed requests so: added `suspend` and removed `Deferred`:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("user/info/")
suspend fun getUserInfo(@Field("token") token: String): UserInfoResponse


override suspend fun getUserInfo(token: String): UserInfoResponse =
    service.getUserInfo(token)
```

Then in interactor (or simply when called the method `getUserInfo(token)`) removed `await()`:

```
override suspend fun getUserInfo(token: String): UserInfoResponse =
    // api.getUserInfo(token).await() - was before.
    api.getUserInfo(token)
```

UPDATE

Once I encountered a situation when downloading PDF files required removing `suspend` in Api class. See [How to download PDF file with Retrofit and Kotlin coroutines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974908/how-to-download-pdf-file-with-retrofit-and-kotlin-coroutines).

Comment: My answer was short and on point but your answer is complete with sources and everything. You can accept your own answer.

Comment: @EugenPechanec, nevertheless, you made a nice work and wasted time, and you were the first. At least, you deserve +10.

Comment: I don't do it for the points, it's fine. I appreciate your gesture.

Comment: Thank you @CoolMind. You saved my bacon!

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec Where is your answer?

Comment: @TheincredibleJan Hi, I deleted it because this answer is essentially the same but more complete.

Answer (score 16):

In my case I was missing the `CoroutineCallAdapterFactory` in my Retrofit initialization. Retrofit v2.5.0

Before:

```kotlin
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                .client(httpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
```

After: (working code)

```kotlin
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                .client(httpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
                .build()
```

Comment: Well, what version of Retrofit do you use?

Comment: @CoolMind   implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'

Comment: Ah, I see. Then, it makes sense. But I advise to upgrade to 2.6.0. Requests make simplier.

Comment: @CoolMind by the way in your question there's 2.5.0 version ;). In any case I just tested my code and it works for 2.6.0 version too

Comment: Hah, I was upgrading from 2.5.0 to 2.6.0 and caught that exception. Currently it is Ok. Surprised that it works for 2.6.0.

Comment: Addition of Code  .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory()) helped

Answer (score 0):

This error may persist even after adding the `suspend` keyword to your method. It may happen that calls with `suspend` functions are not supported by your Retrofit version. Upgrade your Retrofit version to [`2.6.0`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-260-2019-06-05) or greater for `suspend` functions support.